# VBA runs very slow on changing external link

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel file in which cell A1 contains the formula:

```
=C:\folder1\[1.xls]Sheet1!A1
```

and relatively for all cells up to H100.

Now I wish to change the formula for A1 to (similarly for other cells up to H100)

```
=C:\folderA\[A.xls]Sheet1!A1
```

Originally I recorded a macro to do this by a find and replace statement

```
Sub replace()

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Range("A1:H100").replace What:="folder1\[1.xls]", Replacement:="folderA\[A.xls]", _
       LookAt:= xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
       ReplaceFormat:=False

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

But it takes over 10 minutes to do that and on the bottom-left corner of excel, it says "Link: ---" (loading...)

Are there any alternative method?

Comment: yes. open both the prior and new files you are linking to first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that (*it takes less than a second*)

```
Sub ReplaceInaFormula()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("A1:H100")
        c = Replace(c.Formula, "folder1\[1.xls]", "folderA\[A.xls]")
    Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work on my computer...
If I press F8 to trace the macro, I can see the values are updated one by one once its formula has been changed. Seems that .EnableEvents = False does not work on my computer?

Comment: Now I simply replace the formula in the first row, and then copy and paste the formula down to the bottom. It saves me some time but each execution still takes about one minute :(

Comment: @Pingu `Unfortunately that does not work on my computer` doesn't give me any clue why it doesnt work - it should based on the description of your problem.

Comment: With your code provided my computer still takes over 10 minutes to run

Comment: @Pingu are you mapping to a network drive by any chance?

Comment: yes I am using a network drive. I just replace it by C:\ in my question to simplify the problem.

Comment: @Pingu well, this explains why it takes so long. You should have mentioned that your question originally. Mapping a network drive just takes long time and there is no way to fasten the process really

Comment: sorry for not mentioning that in my question. I will try to move the files to my local drive before running the macro. Thanks anyway!